# Why different random_states in ML model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I recently read that specifying a number for the random_state ensures to get the same results in each run.

Why do I use then random_state=1 when splitting the data into training and validation sets but random_state=0 for creating the model?

I would have expected them to be both the same value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

data = pd.read_csv('../input/fifa-2018-match-statistics/FIFA 2018 Statistics.csv')
y = (data['Man of the Match'] == "Yes")  # Convert from string "Yes"/"No" to binary
feature_names = [i for i in data.columns if data[i].dtype in [np.int64]]
X = data[feature_names]
train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)
my_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,
                                  random_state=0).fit(train_X, train_y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't read too much into the number itself. Basically, the random_state refers to numpys random number generator `numpy.random.seed()` and ensures that the random numbers you create are always seeded exactly the same. Initializing with 1 will give you a different sequence than with 0. Since the split uses the random numbers for different purposes (splitting the data) than the random forest (introducing randomness to trees, e.g. with selecting sub-features for a tree, etc.). Yet, the number you give it matters little - it is only to ensure the reproducibility of your draws. To see that you might set the seed, e.g. `numpy.random.seed(42)` and then draw several random numbers numpy.random.rand(). Resetting again with 42 and repeating the draws will give you the same sequence.

From time to time (after setting everything up satisfactorily) it might be wise to get rid of the set random_state to see how your results look like repeatedly with more randomness included. Trying other values (or no seed at all) gives you a sense of how independent and valid your results are in the end. If you need to compare and reproduce the results exactly, the seed should be given.